# Why variable declared without a var in object method does not become a global variable?

Tags: javascript

Could anyone please explain me..

Why `baz` which is declared without a `var` is not becoming a global `variable`?

```
const foo = {
   bar(baz) {

   if (!baz)
   baz = 1;

   }
}
```

Comment: Function arguments are automatically local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's declared as a function parameter<sup>1</sup>:

```
const foo = {
   bar(baz) {
//     ^-------- here

       if (!baz)
           baz = 1;
   }
}
```

*(`bar` is a function declared using ES2015 [method definition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-method-definitions) syntax.)*

If it weren't a parameter, for instance like this:

```
const foo = {
   bar() {
//     ^----------------- no baz
       if (!baz)
           baz = 1;
   }
}
```

...then when `foo.bar()` is called, if `baz` weren't defined, it would be a `ReferenceError` (because the [*Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)<sup>2</sup> only applies to *assigning* to undeclared symbols, not reading from them).

---

<sup>1</sup> We frequently call these "arguments" loosely, but "argument" would technically be the actual value passed on a given call; see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments) for the distinction.

<sup>2</sup> That's a post on my anemic little blog.

Comment: I was about to answer the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a [parameter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Parameter)

Including it in the function declaration implicitly declares it for the given function scope.

Answer (score 1):

Because you set it as a function's parameter. In order for a var to become 'global' (which can weaken the resiliency of programs and should be avoided) you should declare it outside of your function.